# Some easy inequality for a new day :)))

Tags: inequality

I'll call expression of this form "innocent"
$$\frac{M}{x^2+y^2+z^2} + \frac{N}{xy+yz+zx}$$
if we apply some inequality (like AM-GM, Bunyakovsky,...) and we still preserve the equality at $a=b=c=\text{some value}$
What is the condition of $M$ and $N$ to make the expression up there become innocent?
There is a question in my test that has the expression of that form:
$$\text{Given $x+y+z=1$, prove that: }\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}+\frac{3}{xy+yz+zx}\ge12$$
I start applying AM-GM and the result is NOT true, I start to become panicking in the last 15 minutes, and it cost me 2/20 pts. Although I know the equality happens at is $x=y=z=\frac{1}{3}$, but I can't prove it.
(Source: Exam for excellent students in grade 8 in Vietnam)
$$\text{1: No DIFFERENTIATING (I'm a grade 8 student)}$$
$$\text{2: Of course $x,y,z$ must be POSITIVE to apply anything}$$

Comment: $(-1,-1,3)$  gives $  \frac{1}{11}  + \frac{3}{-5}= \frac{-28}{55}$

Comment: @WillJagy I think he missed the condition $x,y,z>0$.

Comment: of course $x,y,z$ must be positive

Answer (score 4):

First note that $(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)$, if we denote $t=xy+yz+zx$, we have
$$\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}+\frac{3}{xy+yz+zx}=\frac{1}{1-2t}+\frac{3}{t}$$
since $x+y+z=1$. By $xy+yz+zx\leq\frac{1}{3}(x+y+z)^2=\frac{1}{3}$, we know it suffices to minimize
$$f(t):=\frac{1}{1-2t}+\frac{3}{t},\quad0<t\leq\frac{1}{3}.$$
Differentiating directly yields
$$f'(t)=\frac{2}{(1-2t)^2}-\frac{1}{t^2}=\frac{-10t^2+12t-3}{(1-2t)^2t^2}<0,\quad 0<t\leq\frac{1}{3}.$$
Hence we know $f(t)\geq f(\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{3}}+9=12$. Then we are done!

(PS: It is easy to see that " = " holds iff $x=y=z=\frac{1}{3}$.)

Comment: Sorry, but no differentiating here, I'm just a grade 8 student